# Erro em ler e comparar números de uma matriz

Tags: c, array, matriz

O programa deve ler um número e comparar com os números de uma matriz 3x3 qualquer se o número pertencer a uma coluna da matriz ele deve imprimir a posição, quando digito 1 ele imprime duas posições, porém o 1 está apenas em uma posição.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () 
{
    int matriz[3][3];
    matriz[1][1] = 1;
    matriz[1][2] = 2;
    matriz[1][3] = 3;
    matriz[2][1] = 4;
    matriz[2][2] = 5;
    matriz[2][3] = 6;
    matriz[3][1] = 7;
    matriz[3][2] = 8;
    matriz[3][3] = 9;
    int coluna, linha, numero;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    fflush(stdin);

    for (linha = 1; linha < 4; linha ++){
        for (coluna = 1; coluna < 4; coluna ++) {
            if(numero == matriz[linha][coluna]){
                printf ("\nA posicao do numero eh linha: %d e coluna: %d", linha, coluna);
            }
        }
    }
    if (numero < 1 || numero > 9){
        printf ("Nao encontrado!");
    }
}
```

Comment: E bem simples. Quando você cria uma matriz de 3x3 por exemplo, na verdade você so pode variar de 0 ate 2, ou seja se você criar uma matriz [N] , sera acessível de 0 até N-1

Comment: Obrigada, simples mesmo hahaha ;)

Comment: @KarenSantos A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Vetores em quase todas as linguagens de programação começam do zero e não do 1. Então para 3 elementos deve variar entre 0 e 2, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int matriz[3][3];
    matriz[0][0] = 1;
    matriz[0][1] = 2;
    matriz[0][2] = 3;
    matriz[1][0] = 4;
    matriz[1][1] = 5;
    matriz[1][2] = 6;
    matriz[2][0] = 7;
    matriz[2][1] = 8;
    matriz[2][2] = 9;
    int coluna, linha, numero;
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    for (linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++) {
        for (coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++) {
            if (numero == matriz[linha][coluna]) printf("\nA posicao do numero eh linha: %d e coluna: %d", linha, coluna);
        }
    }
    if (numero < 1 || numero > 9) printf("Nao encontrado!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1HgnUP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cluhhktp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ComparingMatrix.c).